# How to use ARC converter for a single file in a ARC project?

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting, converters, automated-refactoring

The project is already an ARC project.

But some files are manually disabled arc by putting a -fno-objc-arc flag in its compiler flags.

Now I want use xcode's arc convert tool to convert some of the non-arc file into arc. How can I do this?

Since the project in now already arc. If I try to run the convert tool it just generate too many errors no matter how many files selected

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want the tool, you could just move the source(s) to a dedicated transitionary target (e.g. static library) and then just convert that target.

If all else fails, just remove `-fno-objc-arc` from that source, then review properties and remove the compiler warnings, etc.

Comment: New > Target > Cocoa Touch Static Library, adding the offending files to the Target, disabling ARC in Build Settings for the Target and then Refactor > Convert to Objective-C did the trick. Thanks!